# Get ID value of a dojo combobox selected item

Tags: dojo

```
    var xhrArgs = {
     url: "../Person/GetAll",
         handleAs: "json",
         preventCache: true,
       load: function (data, ioargs) {
            var jsonString = dojo.toJson(data)
            var dataStore = new dojo.store.Memory({ data:
            dojo.fromJson(jsonString) });
    var personCmb = dijit.byId('cmbSingers');
                        if (personCmb == null)
 {
     var cobox = new dijit.form.ComboBox({ id: "cmbSingers", name: "Name", store: dataStore, searchAttr: "Name" }, "cmbSingers");

                                cobox.startup();
                            }

     function cmbSingers_OnSelected() {

               alert(dijit.byId('cmbSingers').get('value')); **this return the Text, But I want to get Id of Select value**     

            }
```

Comment: you need to tell, how your json looks. combobox has only the valueAttr 'at-hand', so loop your json, while matching item.name against cobox.get("value") and pull item like that. Many stores has a query facility which leverages exactly this lookup

Comment: It like Id,Name,Age so can u say how to do it

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a solution to this in 2016+...
I ran into the same situation and found a way to get the value of selected options from Dojo ComboBox.  Instead of just using .value or .get('value'), use .item.value:

```
dijit.byId('someComboBox').item.value
```

.item will return an Object like this for you to use:
**Object {id: "1", value: "1", name: "One"}**

To elaborate... say you define the options for your ComboBox by using a **select** like so:

```
<select dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="someComboBox" maxlength="30">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Say you select the "One" option.
Calling **dijit.byId('someComboBox').value** will return **"One"**,
but calling **dijit.byId('someComboBox').item.value** will return **"1"**

Answer (score 0):

Mkay, json is like so?

`{ identifier: 'Id', items: [ { Id: '1', name:'foo', age: 12 }, { Id: '2', name:'bar', age: 30 } ] }`

And you have `dijit.form.ComboBox` in variable `cobox`, your `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore` in variable `store`.

```
dojo.connect(cobox, "onChange", function() {

  var val = this.get("value"),
    id = "",
    matcher = new RegExp("^" + val + "$");

  dojo.some(store._arrayOfAllItems, function(item, idx) {

   if(matcher.test(store.getValue(item, "name")) {
      id = store.getValue(item, "Id");
      return true; // breaks .some loop
   }
  });

});
```